# Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version L declared in library com.android.support

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a problem - I imported the project in Android Studio. When I run the project I get the following error:

*Error:Execution failed for task ':driverNotes:processDebugManifest'.*

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version L declared in library com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 19
}
```

**Dependencies in build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile project(':vKOpenAuthActivity')
    compile project(':easyFousquareActivity')
    compile project(':pullToRefresh')
    compile project(':volley') 
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'   
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclientandroidlib-1.2.0.jar')

}
```

I used java 7. How can I get rid of this error message?

Comment: Please change the title so that it describes the problem.

Comment: i hate your question title.

Comment: ok, but I change title. So what do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android L Preview build cannot target previous Android version. I think com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1 is built for Android L Preview only, try to change the version to 20+ pending v21 release

EDIT :

It's possible that Google Play Services includes android-support-v4:21.0.0-rc1 . Avoid using + in gradle dependencies (i use it only for minor versions), last version of Google Play Services is 5.2.08 from Android L Preview, try to replace `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'` with `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'`

Comment: I'm a little not understand how to do it?

Comment: Edited answer, i think it's caused by play-services

Comment: Check all linked projects and set the same version of android-support-v4 on each project

Comment: thnks, I set 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+' in facebook SDK and this help me! Thank you very much!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting these problems nowadays (now that Lollipop is available), then it may mean that you're using an old version of the support library. As noted in the [known issues on the Android Tools site](http://tools.android.com/knownissues):

> If your build fails with an error message like this:
>
> :app:processDebugManifest app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:0:0 Error:
>   uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version L declared in library app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.0-rc1/AndroidManifest.xml
>   Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage
>
> you are using an obsolete version of the Android support libraries. Open up the SDK manager and update to the latest (non-preview) versions.